# limit number of threads C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to run a loop with many interactions so i thought of using threads, but I dont know how to control the number of thread:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 45856582; i = i + 10000)
{
    string result = request.Get(String.Format(mold, i));
    Worker temp = new Worker(i, i + 10000);
    Thread th = new Thread( new ThreadStart( temp.DoWork ));
    th.Start();
}
```

This loop would create too many threads, how can I make it in a way that the loop will stop and wont create more threads than a certain number and wait for one of the created threads to be done in order to continue?

This is the worker class :

```
public class Worker
{
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex   = 0;

    public Worker(int startIndex , int endIndex)
    {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex   = endIndex;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
            // Do Work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe use ThreadPool or Parallel classes ? Usually they automatically do good job with threads count

Comment: I'd definitely be looking at [`Parallel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx) `For` or `ForEach` here.

Comment: Does `// Do Work` involve any IO? If so, the answer might be different.

Comment: Please also take a look at the Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you change your entire code to use the `Parallel` class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401(v=vs.110).aspx

```
// Options to the set maximum number of threads. 
// This is not necessary, .NET will try to use the best amount of cores there is. (as pointed out by Panagiotis Kanavos)
// Overload of method is available without the options parameter
var options = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 // maximum number of threads
};

const int batchSize = 1000;
int totalSize = 45856582;
int loops = totalSize / batchSize;

// if there is a rest in the division (in this case 582)
// then add an extra loop
if(totalSize % batchSize != 0) 
    loops++;

// The body on the loop
Action<int> loopBody = i =>
{
    Worker temp = new Worker(i * batchSize, i * batchSize + batchSize);
    temp.DoWork();
};

// The result. Check for loopResult.IsCompleted if everything went correctly
var loopResult = Parallel.For(0, loops, options, loopBody);
```

Or you could use an overload of the method to support cancelling etc.

Comment: The default of as many tasks as there are cores is suitable most of the time. The DOP should be set only if throttling is required, or if the tasks are known to have delays, eg web requests.

Comment: True, he asked for a certain number... But agreed. Will make a comment in my code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Changed

Comment: It would be better to increment i by thousand ( i = i + 1000) because i`m adding things to my database and its better to add them in batches to i`m adding 1000 each time. How do you do that in this case solution?

Comment: Shouldnt it be :
'Worker temp = new Worker(i*batchSize, i*batchSize + batchSize);'

Also, I just used 
'totalSize = 46000000;'
 and at the end of the Worker contructor :
'if(endIndex > 45856582) this.endIndex = 45856582;'
to deal with the rest

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: If my answer helpt you, you can mark it as accepted so other users know my answer helpt you.

Comment: @kadzu and yes, I updated my code to have the `i * batchSize` in it. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Try Parallel.For : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10; //max threads

Parallel.For(0, 45856582, options, i => { 
    Worker temp = new Worker(i, i + 10000);
    temp.DoWork();
} );
```

Comment: Your code will run things multiple times. Your code will do batches of 10000 a total of 45856582 times. Not the plan I guess

Comment: your right, was meant to broadly point in the right direction rather than write the code for him! should of specified the caveat in the answer.